# sccm 2012 prerequisite windows 8.1 usmt fail

Tags: sccm

When i installing SCCM 2012 on server 2012 r2 on prerequisite get a fail error that USMT for win 8.1 not install. I installed adksetup and download components and reset the server but this error is show.Please help me!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrBmP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agnZM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error list of Prerequisite can be solve in one shot by installing ADK tool.

Microsoft Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) for Windows 8.1 which can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982).

[image]

Note: Do not change the installation path.